# How to deal with errors of defining data types in pandas' read_csv ()?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with 118,000 rows and 80 columns. I would like to select 8 columns from the table. I am reading the file using the pandas function  `pd.read_csv` command as:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, sep='|',
                 usecols=[1,3,4,5,37,40,51,76])
```

I would like to change the data type of each column inside of `read_csv` using `dtype={'5': np.float, '37': np.float, ....}`, but this does not work.

There is a message that column 5 has mixed types. The command `print(df.dtypes)` shows all columns of the type object. When I examine the column 5, I cannot see any problems. I have to change the data type for each column separately using pd.to_numeric.

My question is: Is there a way of setting data types inside `read_csv` and what is the problem in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you see the warning that your column has mixed types, but you only see numbers there, it could be that missing values are causing the problem.

In Pandas 1.0.0, a [new function has been introduced](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#convert-dtypes-method-to-ease-use-of-supported-extension-dtypes) to try to solve that problem. Namely, the `Dataframe.convert_dtypes` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes)).

You can use it like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, sep='|', usecols=[1,3,4,5,37,40,51,76])
df = df.convert_dtypes()
```

then check the type of the columns

```
print(df.dtypes)
```

Comment: Thanks for the new function. I solved this problem by converting columns datatype after importing them into df. I passed a list of columns I needed to convert into for loop. That worked. For example:  col_list=['col1', 'col2', 'col5', etc...]    and than using for loop    
                       for  col in col_list:   df[col]=pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')    Thanks

Comment: @Liliana just be careful that you have `errors='coerce'` which could mean that you lose some data unwillingly.

Comment: Thanks. Good idea to compare input and output files.

Answer (score 0):

You could try just using your own solution, replacing `np.float`:

```
dtype={'5': pd.to_numeric, '37': np.float, ....}
```

Or make a function that does what you want:

```
def convert(val):
    try:
        return np.float(val)
    except:
        return float(val)
    except:
        return pd.to_numeric(val)

    return val
```

Then:

```
dtype={'5': convert, '37': np.float, ....}
```

That is a bit exaggerated, but you get the idea  :)